# Transform rows in CSVs in map reduce way on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

Just wonder if there is a map-reduce way on AWS data pipeline or AWS EMR so that I can transform **GZIPPED CSV** files on S3 into DynamoDB backup format?

I think it could be done by an EMRActivity in data pipeline but I'm very new to Big Data, not figure this out.

The CSV schema is:

```
id,name,date
1,abc,2021-08-01
2,bcd,2021-08-02
```

It needs to be tramformed into DynamoDB backup format:

```
{"id":{"s":"1"},"name":{"s":"abc"},"uploadDate":{"s":"2021-08-01"}}
{"id":{"s":"2"},"name":{"s":"bcd"},"uploadDate":{"s":"2021-08-02"}}
```